# Using batch file without having to press enter at each input

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ip-address, user-input

so I asked a question earlier that I wanted to be able to type within brackets in a batch file, which the answer to my q was not possible. so I need some more feedback then just that. but what im wanting to do here now is when I type an ip address, instead of typing "127.0.0.1" and then pressing [Eneter] id rather it just continue in the batch file when I type "127.0.0.1"

Anyone know a good way of doing this?

Comment: ...and what if the user was trying to type 127.0.0.10?

Comment: IMO you have to write your own input parser (in C/Pascal/Basic ... whatever) to realize that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide batch some way to determine **what** is the IP adress you are trying to enter. There should be a distinct character designating the end of the input otherwise cmd just can't knwo where the input will end. As rightfully pointed out in a comment by j__m if you are trying to input 127.0.0.10 thne you would not batch to think you have entered 127.0.0.1 before you manage to type the 0 right? In general always ask your self is there a way I could do that, before asking is there a way to make the computer do something. If **you** can't tell where the input ends if there is no enter at the end I doubt computer will do better. A computer is just a machine and it does what you tell it to.

Answer (score 2):

At this site: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3428 **GetKey.exe** auxiliary program is described. This program read a key and immediately return its Ascii code via ERRORLEVEL, so it does not require <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to continue. In the same site :ReadLine.bat example program is shown; it emulates `SET /P` command with the aid of **Show.exe** (another auxiliary program), that is, <kbd>BackSpace</kbd> key delete the last typed character and <kbd>Enter</kbd> key terminate the input. You may modify :ReadLine subroutine to suit specific needs and several examples of this feature are shown.

For example, the subroutine below is a modified version of :ReadLine that just read decimal digits and points, and continue "automatically" after read 9 characters (like "127.0.0.1"):

```
:Read9DigitsAndPoints var=["prompt"]
set Point=46
set Slash=47
rem set Digit_0=48
set Digit_9=57
set %1=
set len=0
if "%~2" neq "" Show %~2
:nextKey
   GetKey
   set key=%errorlevel%
   if %key% geq %Space% (
      rem Ascii character: ignore characters that are not digits nor points
      if %key% lss %Point% goto nextKey
      if %key% gtr %Digit_9% goto nextKey
      if %key% equ %Slash% goto nextKey
      Show %key%
      for /F "delims=" %%a in ('Show %key%') do set "%1=!%1!%%a"
      set /A len+=1
   ) else if %key% equ %BackSpace% (
      if defined %1 (
         Show %BackSpace% %Space% %BackSpace%
         set "%1=!%1:~0,-1!"
         set /A len-=1
      ) else (
         Show %Bell%
      )
   )
if %len% neq 9 goto nextKey
echo/
exit /B
```

You may further modify this subroutine in order to read a well-formatted IP address (ie: four groups of digits separated by 3 points), so the routine continue after the user enter the IP as you want. By the while, do *you* know at what moment you want the routine to continue? After read the first digit after the third point?

Antonio